# copying content of one file to other using system calls

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

Here I am trying to copy the content of one file into other(unix) using the `open` `read` and `write` system calls but for some reason the code is running for infnite time... 
and i am not getting the error so if you could help me out!!

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int args,char *ar[])
{
char *source=ar[1];
char *dest="def.txt";
char *buf=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*120);
int fd1,fd2;
fd1=open(source,O_CREAT,0744);
fd2=open(dest,O_CREAT,0744);
while(read(fd1,buf,120)!=-1)
{
printf("%s",buf);
//printf("Processing\n");
write(fd2,buf,120);
}
printf("Process Done");
close(fd1);
close(fd2);
}
```

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in your code.

- The first and most obvious is, that you never check for errors (`malloc`, `open`, `close`). In case you are wondering: yes, you do need to check `close`.
- Then your `open` calls are not correct, because you do not specify a file access mode. Quoting `man 2 open`: `The  argument flags must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.` You are invoking undefined behavior here.
- Also your handling of the return value of `read` is wrong. You only check for errors, but if no error happens, your program will loop indefinitely. Note that end-of-file is not considered an error. Instead `read` returns the number of bytes read (which you don't check). Upon end-of-file the return value is 0.
- Your main function does not return a value. Try running `gcc` or `clang` with `-Wall -Wextra` to see issues like these.
- Casting the return value of `malloc` is considered harmful by the way.